# REACT: Why after clicking on the button color of h1 is not changing? (but if you change color to i.e innerText then it works)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

useEffect changes the css property but it takes no effect on the screen. But only so if I change color or bacgroundColor - innerText works just fine.

```
export function App(props) {

const [state1, setState1] = useState(true);
const hRef = useRef();

const clickHandler = () => {
    setState1(!state1);
}

useEffect(()=>{

    hRef.current.color=state1?'blue':'green';
    setState1(state1);

},[state1]);


return (
    <div className='App'>
        <h1 ref={hRef}>Hello {`${state1}`}.</h1>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change State</button>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: Add it this way=>`hRef.current.style.color`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really change things in react using `refs if you don't really need to.

Comment: Also, why are you calling setState1 in useEffect with state1 dependency

Comment: For me this `useEffect` looks like an infinite loop and it should throw an error

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Is there meant to be a name in that h1?

Comment: OMG.. this is embarrassing - thank you sir! It was about current.style.color instead of current.color. (setState1(state1) was just testing if I get re-render with it, I forgot to delete it - and yes it would be an infinite loop if it was !state1 inside of the setter, also what's inside of h1 was just for testing purpose of changing state). What you mean by I don't need to useRefs - is there a better way to change css properties?

Comment: What about <h1 style={{ color: state1?'blue':'green'}}>Hello {`${state1}`}.</h1>

Than yout dont need ref and also hook does not make sence :)

Comment: As @DanielLazar mentioned, try not to declare redundant states. Also `useEffect` was intended to do what lifecycles methods in class components do, synchronization between imperative and declarative logic ... . What you want to achieve can easily be done using event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

WRT to not needing to use `ref` here's an example that stores the "active" state of the button, and uses CSS classes to change the colour of the heading.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Accept a name prop
function App({ name }) {
  
  // Initialise the state as false
  const [ active, setActive ] = useState(false);
  
  // The button updates the state
  function handleClick() {
    setActive(!active);
  }

  // We create class string which is determined by
  // the current state
  const cn = `heading ${active ? 'active' : ''}`;

  // And then apply that string to the `className` prop
  // of the heading
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1 className={cn}>Hello {name}.</h1>
      <button
        className="change"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >Change State
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App name="Wojtek" />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.heading { padding: 0.3em; background-color: lightgreen; }
.active { background-color: lightblue; }
.change:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffffa0; border-radius: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```